# Spoofing referer by injecting javascript

Tags: jquery

I've been asked a question by one of my friends as a brain teaser, is it possible to spoof a referer by injecting a link and then simulating a click? So I decided to try, I tried it with gmail.com and ran this through firebug javascript console.

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
headID.appendChild(newScript);

$("#signIn").html('<a href="http://google.com" id="testing">Hmm</a>');
$("#testing").click();
```

It's interesting tho, first I get an error because it seems that jquery is not loaded fast, but the main important thing is that the element actually doesn't get clicked, any ideas?

Comment: There is an add-on that can do it: [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/). Not completely sure what you want to accomplish though.

Comment: Actually I have that, whole point of this is just to see if it would work if I injected a link via javascript and simulated a click :)

Comment: Why wouldn't it? I suppose you understand all this happens at your browser and not in Gmail servers, if that's what you thought

Comment: Then running it from the console won't tell you anything as console code has more permissions.

Comment: Yeah but would the href'ed URL think i'm coming from gmail or not? And how come my JS is not working

Comment: Yeah, and? If you want to play around with this, there are easier ways though. `curl --referer` comes to mind

Comment: Yes I know all about that, my point still stands about trying this via javascript, but the surprising thing is that if I print $_SERVER on the receiving script, it does not show gmail.com

Comment: You might be able to spoof a referrer with a FF modify headers addon

Comment: By the way, I use a code slightly modified from this template http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/ to load jQuery in my Greasemonkey scripts. This way you can make sure to run the code only if jQuery was actually loaded and avoid errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `click` event isn't actually emulating a real click event.  It is merely invoking the click event on the object.  Hyperlinks don't (by default) have a click event.  Instead of using the jQuery `.click` function, try using the native javascript `.click` function.

This works:

```
document.getElementById("link").click();
```

This also works:

```
$("#link")[0].click();
```

This will not work:

```
$("#link").click();
```

Demo it at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RfS82/)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but referrer is blank for some reason, hmmm via $_SERVER is blank